# Changing specific field values before Jackson serialization

Tags: java, jackson

Jackson Deserializer has the @JacksonInject annotation to change value before it is deserialized, overriding the original value. Is there a way to do that during serialization?

@JsonView annotation helps with dropping specific fields altogether.

The usecase is before a call is made to a REST api, Jackson should override specific sensitive field values ( which ever is annotated ) with a special character ( like * etc)

Answer (score 0):

```
 @JsonProperty
    private String  name = "Leghrib Badreddine";
 @JsonValue
    public String toJson(){
        return "Mr." + this.name;
    }
```

Comment: @JsonAppendwill add another field. I am looking to replace the value of an existing field. `{ name : “abc”} to { name : “**” }`

Comment: what about this @user2676543 ?